# How msg.sender address gets generated in smartcontract?

Tags: transactions, contract-deployment, addresses

`msg.sender` `(address)`: the sender of the message (current call).

Considering a scenario where a user uses a smart contract and try to perform a transaction. For that particular user msg.sender is the address of that user.

Does this address ever change for that specific user?

On what basis address is given to the caller? How its generated?

Answer (score 2):

The `msg.sender` is always the address of the entity who called the current contract. When a contract calls another contract the `msg.sender` changes. Let me give you some examples.

Assuming we have a EOA (Externally Owned Account) A and contracts B and C. When A calls B the `msg.sender` in B is A's public address. If contract B also calls contract C, `msg.sender` in contract C is B's (contract) address.

So the address of a user never changes (assuming he uses the same account) but the `msg.sender` changes in contracts based on which entity initiated the call to that contract.

There is also `tx.origin` which is always A in the aforementioned example (in every contract which is called in the transaction from A), but this should typically not be used.

Comment: "So the address of a user never changes (assuming he uses the same account) but the msg.sender changes in contracts based on which entity initiated the call to that contract." With that being said, if the user uses a different account from what he uses earlier to perform transaction then msg.sender will have a different address? Does this mean msg.sender is depended of what account user uses from his wallet?

Comment: Yes, one user account means one private key which results in one public key which results in one public address. Different account has a different private key and therefore different public address.